# Ajax, JQuery, GET request with PHP error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a very basic webpage which contains of two files, phpcode.php.cgi and frontpage.php.cgi.
I have dropdowns that should be populated dynamically, however I can't get the request/reponse to work. The ID of the dropdown is "start".
I have an Ajax request in the frontpage file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#start").change(function(){
            alert("dropdown changed");
            var val = $('#start').val();
            $.ajax({ 
               type: "GET",
               data: {Station_Nr : val},
               url: "phpcode.php.cgi",
               success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
               }
            });
        });
    });
```

and my phpfile looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['Station_Nr'])) {
    echo "it works";
};
?>
```

It tries to request from url../phpcode.php.cgi?Station_Nr=27
When I try to enter the page I get a 500 error.
According to chrome, the error lies in the row which starts with $.ajax.

I have included:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your file extensions are confusing - are they PHP files or CGI files? If the former, as you sure that your server is setup to interpret and execute them using the PHP engine? To help debug this, you can check the network tab of the console. It should show the response text of the 500 error request 
which should hopefully give you a description of the problem. Also note that you appear to have included jQuery.js twice. I'd suggest removing `1.12.0.min.js` and moving the reference to `3.2.1` to the top

Comment: If you get an 500 Server error you should also have something in your error log. Can you show us the error message from the logfile!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The files are CGI. An issue is that it is the schools web server and therefore no logs are available, PHP are supposed to  work if I have this extension (so far except the request it does). The responsetext only states that there is more information in the server log. In mozilla -> network -> cause = xhr. In chrome: GET url../phpcode.php.cgi?Station_Nr=10 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ frontpage.php.cgi:99
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:588

Answer (score 0):

In the top of the file is #!/usr/bin/php5 located.
Here was \r\n added because of Windows and the transfer method was binary. The Apache server responded with an error and when replacing \r\n with \n it works.

Answer (score -1):

When you obtain a 500 error is because something is wrong in server not in client, use /phpcode.php.cgi in $.ajax to use an absolute path just in case.